# Как функция получает аргументы?

Tags: javascript

```js
let worker = {
  slow(min, max) {
    alert(`Called with ${min},${max}`);
    return min + max;
  }
};

function cachingDecorator(func, hash) {
  let cache = new Map();
  return function() {
    let key = hash(arguments); // (*)
    if (cache.has(key)) {
      return cache.get(key);
    }

    let result = func.call(this, ...arguments); // (**)

    cache.set(key, result);
    return result;
  };
}

function hash(args) {
  return args[0] + ',' + args[1];
}

worker.slow = cachingDecorator(worker.slow, hash);

alert( worker.slow(3, 5) ); // работает
alert( "Again " + worker.slow(3, 5) ); // аналогично (из кеша)
```

Не разберусь как аргументы (3, 5) попадают в let key = hash(arguments)?

Comment: arguments - встроенная переменная, это массив всех арументов текущей ф-ции

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, array-like, у него нет методов массива, но есть свойство length и можно по индексу обратиться к элементу

Comment: @Grundy так точно